# Error: Unexpected token Y while creating phone gap project

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-cli

I am using the following command

```
sudo cordova create helloworld com.helloworld Hello World
```

above command is not working because in the third argument (Hello World) there is space involved...so it is giving

> Error: Unexpected token Y

As third argument is display name of app. i want to have the space in the title of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo cordova create "helloworld" com.helloworld "Hello World"
```

Application name should be surrounded by double quotes if its more than Single word. Similar way you can also surround project name by bouble quotes if too more that Single word.

Regards.